# Company internal tool with SSO auth

Tags: website-design, web-app, login, web, single-sign-on

I am developing on a web project for the company I work for that uses SSO to login. You can't use the tool if you don't log in. The app will be available to everybody(dose not require company VPN or specific settings, domain is public) but the SSO will block unwelcome people who try to enter the website.

Until now the log in page was a normal login page with a single button. That page for me at least gave the user some "power" when it comes to making a decision. In this case when you log out, you are redirected to the log in page.

The new idea is to remove that page and when you first enter on the tool's webpage, to be redirected to the SSO provider. In this case when you log out you are redirected directly to the SSO to log in.

Which is the best practice in this case?

Thank you!

ps.: We don't have a UI/UX designer.